# merging two Apple ID accounts/emails

Tags: apple-id

I had an ATT iphone and have changed to the Verizon iphone today. I wanted to sync my apps and google mail/contacts and was told that I had to connect with itunes and it would update.

I opened itunes and plugged in my new phone. Itunes asked to login but would not recognize my password. I clicked the forgot password but I think the email it has was from my old company and not able to be received. Because I have work this weekend with an app I had on my phone, I set up a new account with apple ID to get myself the app for the weekend but now I have two apple IDs. All my purchased apps are on the applie ID that I can not find the password.

How can I merge these to email accounts into one that I can access my purchased Apps?

Comment: Ugh. You can't merge, but there are options. How much money is tied up in the smaller account? How much time do you want to spend unifying things?

Answer (score 1):

Currently apple offers no way of merging accounts. They are rumored to be working on a solution.

In any case you will have to retrieve your Apple ID.
There are 2 ways to do that. You tried the email. the second being the security question:

[image: Select the security question]

The last resort would be contacting apple and trying to get them to change the e-mail address of your account (if you have a credit card attached to your account they might be able to authenticate you using this).

Comment: "They are working on a solution." Apple has not, to my knowledge, indicated that they are working on a solution to that, although it was a widely repeated rumor last year in the lead up to iCloud. I certainly hope they are (and eventually do) as I have 2+ Apple IDs myself, but I'm not holding my breath. Just FYI/FWIW.

Comment: They acknowledged the problem... at least which got me to believe they are doing something about it. But you might be right I will edit my answer. -_- Wishful thinking.